# ngOnInit() not being invoked - even first time running the Ionic app

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

For an *Ionic* App that has implemented *OnInit* why is *ngInit()* not invoked?  It is not happening even the first time the app/window is opened:

```
export class AudioRecorderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   ...
  async ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit()')  // never printed 
   ...

}
```

Is there a different way to get logic to be executed when creating an *Ionic* component?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `async` statement?

Comment: trying that now ..  oops there are _await_ calls in there ..  ok well I'll comment out and see if your approach allows the hobbled version to work as expected. Ouch - even so it does not get invoked

Comment: Please post the full content of this component and the related module in which it is imported. There is insufficient information here to properly answer the question. It would also be useful to put a console.log in the constructor. Are you certain this component gets properly created? If not, it would explain why init is not called.

Comment: @E.Maggini  Clips are being recorded successfully - thus it is being created and 99% of the logic is being executed.   So the component is working - just not perfectly due to the logic in ngOnInit() not executing.  I can not post the majority of it since it is proprietary.

Comment: OK....and what happens when you add a console.log to constructor? does it log as expected?

Comment: also.....use ionViewWillEnter.....this is an ionic app. While angular lifecycle hooks should work, we always use the ionic ones.

Comment: If the rest of the logic in that component is running - what is the need for the console.log in the constructor?  OK i'll add it but not sure of the value

Comment: I'll look into how to add _ionViewWillEnter()_   it was not clear how to use those ionic events and also when they fire.  E.g. i had already tried _ionViewDidEnter()_ and nothing happened.  Do I need to add something similar to `MyComponent *implements OnInit*` for those to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the *GoogleVoice* extension. After disabling the extension the  `ngOnInit()` proceeded correctly

Answer (score 1):

While in theory ngOnInit should work, try using viewWillEnter instead.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

```
export class AudioRecorderComponent implements viewWillEnter {

 ionViewWillEnter(): void {

     console.log('view will enter');
 }

}
```

Comment: thanks for that piece about `viewWillEnter()` : adding that now..